# Pending transactions from Nano X Ledger Live

Tags: pending-transactions

I have three pending transactions (I think) - only 1 is showing up on Latest Operations on my Nano X Ledger Live - the most recent one.  It's been four days.  I don't think I have the skills to pursue cancel or replace on myetherwallet.  When I go to Etherscan, they don't show up as Pending for some reason - my last transaction listed is months ago - confirmed.  Should I just keep waiting?  If so, for how long?  Will they at least FAIL or be REJECTED?  I'm afraid they will stay this way forever, then what?  Then I won't ever be able to transfer my crypto from Ledger Live, correct?  Thanks in advance for your help. Tom

Comment: Your transaction is probably underpriced. What is your address? It will help people assess what you should do.

Comment: 0x7b1316476Ff35741901DaEE35CE5C2B8bF46F3C8    thanks for your help

Comment: That's an address with no pending transactions. Maybe it has finally mined?

Answer (score 0):

Underpriced transactions may stick in the mempool for two weeks or so before expiring.

If the transaction is seriously underpriced it is not going to be picked up by EtherScan in the first place. Usually these transactions do not go through at all. But the safest bet is figure out how to speed up the tranaction or cancel it using MyEtherWallet. It is very technical task, especially with Ledger, so prepare be spend one or two days to figure it out.

Comment: Speeding up a transaction is fairly simple nowadays. There's a full guide on how to do it with MyCrypto [here](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/sending/checking-or-replacing-a-transaction-after-it-has-been-sent).